# iLife installation help

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, macbook, macosx

I am a 7th grade student doing a documentary for school. My friend recently converted my  Early 2007 Macbook with OSX Lion to Ubuntu 14.04. However, I was not aware that I would lose iLife '11. I need it for my project. I have the installation disk, is there anyway to get it back? Please don't suggest any alternative programs.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no way to run Mac software on Ubuntu AFAIK. Wine only works with Windows software, so you're out of luck when it comes to that.

However, you may be able to use a virtual machine ([VirtualBo](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)x, [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/7_0), etc) to install OSX and use iLife that way.